# Playing system recorded sound

Tags: naudio

I am trying to record my system sound and stream it over tcp to then be played on another pc, but my problem is that then i play the sound i recieve it is playing super slow. I'm using WasapiLoopbackCapture to record system sound, but when i try to play the bytes i record it is playing slowly.
How do i fix this? If i write to a file and then play it, it sounds fine, but i cant directly play the bytes.

This is the code i use to play the sound.

```
bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(CaptureInstance.WaveFormat);
savingWaveProvider = new SavingWaveProvider(bufferedWaveProvider, outputFilePath);
soundPlayer = new WasapiOut();
soundPlayer.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
soundPlayer.Play();
```

And later in the code when i recieve a buffer over TCP i add the sample.

```
bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the wave formats match exactly. Typically WASAPI loopback capture will be capturing stereo IEEE floating point samples at either 44.1kHz or 48kHz. So the `WaveFormat` of the `BufferedWaveProvider` should be set to exactly the same format as audio is being captured in.

Another issue to be aware of is that you should be using the `BytesRecorded` property of the `DataAvailable` event rather than the length of the buffer. The capture buffer may not always be completely full.

Finally, raw stereo IEEE float samples at 44.kHz or higher is not a very efficient way of transmitting audio over a network. It may just be that your network can't keep up. Typically programs that transmit audio over a network will apply some kind of codec to reduce the bandwidth requirements.

Comment: It does use the same waveformat for recording and playing, and im using the BytesRecorded property, but it still doesn't sound smooth when i play the audio.
For the codec part im looking into it, but just wanted to get the basic record, steam and play to work first.
What else could be wrong, the buffer fills up in no time and crashes.